# CUDA: In warp reduction and volatile keyword

Tags: c++, cuda, reduction

After reading the question and its answer from the following
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733084/cuda-why-is-warp-based-parallel-reduction-slower)

I still have a question remaining in my mind. From my background in C/C++; I understand that using `volatile` has it's demerits. And also it is pointed in the answers that in case of CUDA, the optimizations can replace shared array with registers to keep data if `volatile` keyword is not used.

I want to know what would be the performance issues that can be encountered when calculating (sum) reduction. e.g.

```
__device__ void sum(volatile int *s_data, int tid)
{
    if (tid < 16)
    {
        s_data[tid] += s_data[tid + 16];
        s_data[tid] += s_data[tid +  8];
        s_data[tid] += s_data[tid +  4];
        s_data[tid] += s_data[tid +  2];
        s_data[tid] += s_data[tid +  1];
    }
}
```

I am using in warp reduction. Since all the threads with in warp are in sync, therefore I believe there is no need to use `syncthreads()` construct.

I want to know will removing the keyword `volatile` mess up my sum (due to cuda optimizations)? Can I use reduction such as this without `volatile` keyword.

Since I use this reduction function multiple time, will `volatile` keyword cause any performance degradation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing the volatile keyword from that code *could* break that code on Fermi and Kepler GPUS. Those GPUs lack instructions to directly operate on shared memory. Instead, the compiler must emit a load/store pair to and from register.

What the volatile keyword does in this context is make the compiler honour that load-operate-store cycle and not perform an optimisation that would keep the value of `s_data[tid]` in register. To keep the sum accumulating in register would break the implicit memory syncronisation required to make that warp level shared memory summation work correctly.

Comment: Can you provide me with some code where I can see this breakdown. I am using Fermi Arch based GPU. I executed this reduction without `volatile` as someone suggested and the resulting sum was still correct. With code I could see how the load and would be honored as you mentioned.

Comment: There is a complete discussion of this in the "Fermi compatibility guide for CUDA applications" pdf. Note that I said *could* break. Whether it will depends on compiler, optimisation settings and register pressure in the kernel. Just because your code works with the compiler you are using doesn't mean it will work with every version of the CUDA toolkit in the same way, or that it will be safe with every kernel you might write.

Comment: So therefore it is a better practice to use `volatile` to make sure that summation always works as it is expected to be. Thanks that the exact answer I was looking for.